# How to grep for an exact match for string having non alpha chars?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

So the following grep matches 2 lines.

```
grep -w 1.2.3.4 testfile.csv 
1.2.3.4,Jim,Jonson,000000
1.2.3.4.5,George,Doe,FFFFF
```

How can I make it match exactly and only the specific word? In this example only `1.2.3.4`.
Let's assume that whitespace in the beginning or next to the comma separator 
may appear and I would like this to be if possible cross platform grep.

Comment: should it match this `-1.2.3.4-`?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest:No. No prefix or suffix

Comment: Here's gnu definition for _word_ and _non-word_ characters:`-w` _Select only those lines containing matches that form whole words. The test is that the matching substring must [...] be either at the end of the line or followed by a non-word constituent character.  Word-constituent characters are letters, digits, and the underscore._ As you can see it's quite different than your definition of _non-word_ ... And btw, an unescaped dot matches any character so your `grep -w 1.2.3.4` would also match `1a2b3c4`

Comment: @don_crissti:I want to demark it within the 2 `,` then

Comment: for given sample, `awk -F, '$1=="1.2.3.4"'` should work.. if not, please add some more samples

Comment: or possibly `grep '^ *1\.2\.3\.4,'` ...

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest:Why did you remove your answer?

Comment: @Jim, because you have depreciated my answer and that became as wasting time. You already got some 4-upvoted answer - you may go get consult from it

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest:How did I depreciate it? I apologize if I did.

Answer (score 4):

As noted by [don_crissti](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22142/don-crissti) in comments. The issue in your case is that the pattern trying to match `1.2.3.4` does *not* match the word conditions met for `-w`

Use the PCRE mode in your GNU `grep` if its supported. Using a positive lookahead

```
grep -P '^1\.2\.3\.4(?=,)' file
```

or as recommended by [Sundeep](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/109046/sundeep) without using PCRE just do

```
grep '^1\.2\.3\.4,' file
```

Also for more exact string match, `awk` is easier to do

```
awk -F, -v var="1.2.3.4" '$1==var' file
```

Comment: So with awk I avoid the issues with the regex and escaping `.` etc?

Comment: @Jim : Yes! That’s right.

Comment: I'll add a recommendation for `grep '^ *1\.2\.3\.4 *,' testfile.csv` as trailing whitespace is apparently allowed.